# Heroku cedar stack, thin and eventmachine

Tags: heroku, cedar

Do Heroku Cedar stack apps require thin and eventmachine in Gemfile?

```
gem 'thin'
gem 'eventmahine'
```

What about versions?
On other stacks they were installed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify any gem that you want to use on Cedar stack unlike on Bamboo which had preinstalled gems.

Go with whatever version your application needs,

Comment: Oh, thanks. I've got one more problem with that: on windows I have to use eventmachine version '1.0.0.beta.4.1' in Gemfile (bundle update tries to install 0.12.6 if I don't point exact version and fails - there is not such version for windows), and I push Gemfile with '1.0.0.beta.4.1' on heroku, push fails because heroku can not install '1.0.0.beta.4.1'(