# Heroku, Thin and everything in between

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin, webrick

Looking at the logs, my cedar app currently runs webrick. Obviously, this is not the best choice for production app.

As noted all over the web, I should use Thin webserver.

But I would still like to use the simplicty of webrick on my development machine (windows).

As noted in the comments on [Heroku cedar stack, thin and eventmachine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362303/heroku-cedar-stack-thin-and-eventmachine) the version that can be installed on windows for eventmachine (I also need some explanation on that gem) is 1.0.0.beta4 and heroku doesn't like that..

1. How do I install thin (and eventmachine I guess) only on heroku and keep webrick for all my localhost needs?
2. What is eventmachine and why do I need it?
3. Is there a way to explicitly tell heroku to ignore what I want and use thin?

Comment: To use thin only in production you will need declare this in Gemfile `group :production do; gem 'thin'; end` and put this into Procfile: `web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT` as described in http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Comment: Heroku [recommends Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#webserver) for production apps now

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`, create or change the `production` group to include `thin`:

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'  
end
```

Then, in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) (*a file named `Procfile` placed in the root of your app*), tell Heroku you want to use `thin`, like so:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

That will allow you to keep using Webrick in your local development environment while running `thin` in production on Heroku.

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing, with Rails `3.2.21`, but it says: `bundler: failed to load command: thin (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip installation of `thin` gem on your local machine, call bundler like this:

```
bundle install --without production
```