# Thin Gem Won't Work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, eventmachine, thin

I'm moving from the Bamboo stack to the Cedar one on Heroku, but I'm running into issues trying to run the Thin gem on Heroku.  Locally, I'm running Windows Vista, but I have the same error mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362303/heroku-cedar-stack-thin-and-eventmachine),

When I add the Thin gem to my gemfile, it tries to install eventmachine

(1) When I add `gem "thin"` to my gemfile, I receive an error because it can't install eventmachine 0.12.10.  Also, when I try to commit it to Heroku I receive an error because thin isn't installed locally.

(2) When I add these gems, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7):

(I've tried putting this in a `group :production do` block and without, and in neither case did it work)

```
gem "thin", "1.3.1"
gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.beta.4.1"
```

I receive an error indicating that that eventmachine version can't be found.

(3) When I add the gem manually it installs.

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
```

However, even when I add the Thin gem, it still wants to install the 0.12.10 version of eventmachine, even if I try to specify the 1.3.1 Thin version mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7).

Comment: If you're on the Cedar stack, what's in your Procfile? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: I didn't upload a Procfile yet, I was just going to have what Heroku recommended web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV.  Trying to get the bundle install to work first https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration

Comment: you don't need a procfile if you're only running a web process, Heroku autodetects it and does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help from Heroku.  It turns out I just had to do:

group :production do
 gem 'thin'
end

and then, instead of

```
bundle install
```

you run

```
bundle install --without production
```

Of course this doesn't help if you want to run Thin locally, but for me, Web Brick is fine in development.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 1.0.0.beta.4.1 is only available on win32 based architectures (http://rubygems.org/gems/eventmachine/versions). Your Heorku dynos are ubuntu 64-bit based. Try the following:

```
gem "thin", "1.3.1"
gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.beta.4.1", :group => [:development, :test]
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: "could not find gem 'eventmachine (=1.0.0.beta.4.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile'"  This happens even though I already installed the gem using 'gem install eventmachine --pre'.  It also happens when I remove the :group... part